# ComboBox Virtual Event

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

whenever I try to run a function using ComboBox, I have to include a argument which I don't use in the function so that it can run. I have tried printing the argument and it is showing this "VirtualEvent event x=0 y=0".

I want it to be able to run without any argument but it will show this error:

TypeError: update_day() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given.

How do I remove this 1 positional arguments?

```
def update_day():
some code to run.

trying=ttk.Combobox(popup, font=("times", 14), value=month_option, width=5, textvariable=var2, state="readonly")
trying.place(x=220, y=100)
trying.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", update_day)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind a function to an event, tkinter will always pass an object to the callback. This object, by convention named `event`, describes the event that triggered the callback.

You can't prevent the parameter from being sent, though there are workarounds. The simplest is to make the parameter optional in your function definition.

For example:

```
def update_day(event=None):
    some code to run
```

The above allows the function to accept the event object passed to it, but also allows you to directly call the function without the event object (eg: `update_day()`.

Comment: Can I ask why does ComboBox result in an argument as compared to using command to call function in Label, Button, etc.

Comment: @BarnacleOwn: because that's how bindings work. When you bind an event to a function, tkinter always sends an object which represents the event that triggered the callback. This behavior is not unique to the combobox.